# Displaying the subelement on hover

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML code:

```css
.hormenu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.hormenuParent {
  display: inline;
}

.hormenuParent:hover {
  background: #91c1f7;
}

.hormenuParent:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body style="height:100%;">
  <nav style="background-color:#f2f2f2; padding:4px 10px;">
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">File</a>
      <ul style="display:none;">
        <li>Open</li>
        <li>Save</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">Edit</a>
      <ul style="display:none;">
        <li>Copy</li>
        <li>Undo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">View</a>
      <ul style="display:none;">
        <li>Zoom In</li>
        <li>Zoom Out</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">Tools</a>
      <ul style="display:none;">
        <li>Do X</li>
        <li>Do Y</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">Help</a>
      <ul style="display:none;">
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

I was expecting the `ul` elements to become visible (like a drop down menu), but they don't. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "inline CSS" comes **last in the cascade** and so your `display:block` is overridden.

Remove `style="display:none;"` from the HTML and add it as the default syle to the `ul` css.

```css
.hormenu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.hormenuParent {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  display: none;
}

.hormenuParent:hover {
  background: #91c1f7;
}

.hormenuParent:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav style="background-color:#f2f2f2; padding:4px 10px;">
  <div class="hormenuParent">
    <a href="#" class="hormenu">File</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Open</li>
      <li>Save</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hormenuParent">
    <a href="#" class="hormenu">Edit</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Copy</li>
      <li>Undo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hormenuParent">
    <a href="#" class="hormenu">View</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Zoom In</li>
      <li>Zoom Out</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hormenuParent">
    <a href="#" class="hormenu">Tools</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Do X</li>
      <li>Do Y</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hormenuParent">
    <a href="#" class="hormenu">Help</a>
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using in-line styles for `display:none;`. This will override anything you put in your CSS. Upon removing those and adding `.hormenuParent ul {display: none;}` to your CSS, the lists do reappear on hover. Now you just have to make it pretty!

Here is the adjusted code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>PTFS Dodument Editor</title>
  <style>
    .hormenu {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 0px 10px;
    }
    
    .hormenuParent {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .hormenuParent ul {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .hormenuParent:hover {
      background: #91c1f7;
    }
    
    .hormenuParent:hover ul {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="height:100%;">
  <nav style="background-color:#f2f2f2; padding:4px 10px;">
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">File</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Open</li>
        <li>Save</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">Edit</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Copy</li>
        <li>Undo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">View</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Zoom In</li>
        <li>Zoom Out</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">Tools</a>
      <ul>
        <li>Do X</li>
        <li>Do Y</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hormenuParent">
      <a href="#" class="hormenu">Help</a>
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple CSS that will allow you to display your menu on mouseover:

```
.hormenuParent {
  position:relative;
}
.hormenuParent:hover ul {
  display:block !important;
}

.hormenuParent ul {
  margin-top:0;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  position: absolute;
  background:#f0f0f0;
}
```

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/7mLkdh5u/1/